# Need help for delete canvas shape depending of position (PYTHON)

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm trying to make one function which do thing which depend of a variable tool.
If tool == 1 that create canva rectangle. I want if tool == 5, that delete block from mouse position, everything is working exept delete, I'm probably giving wrong argument but I don't know. Thanks

```
names = {}
i = 0
a = 40
def evn(e):
    xx = c.canvasx(e.x)
    yy = c.canvasy(e.y)
    t = c.find_withtag('point')
    xg = (e.x+GRID/2)//GRID
    yg = (e.y+GRID/2)//GRID
    test=(xg*GRID, yg*GRID)
    if tool==1:
        global i
        global a
        i += 1
        names[i] = (xg*GRID, yg*GRID)
        oc = get_oval_centre(c.bbox(t))
        oc[0] += GRID
        oc[1] += GRID
        test = c.create_rectangle(-12, -12, 12, 12, fill='white', outline='white', tags=test)
        set_oval_coords(test, (xg*GRID, yg*GRID))
    elif tool==5:
        xx = c.canvasx(e.x)
        yy = c.canvasy(e.y)
        t = c.find_withtag('point')
        xg = (e.x+GRID/2)//GRID
        yg = (e.y+GRID/2)//GRID
        oc = get_oval_centre(c.bbox(t))
        oc[0] += GRID
        oc[1] += GRID
        if (xg*GRID, yg*GRID) in names.values():
            print('found')
            c.delete(test)
```

Comment: Why do you think delete isn't working? What happens when you call it? Does it delete the wrong thing? Does it not delete anything? What have you done to debug this? You say you want something to happen if tool == 2, but you didn't provide any code for when tool == 2.

Comment: I think delete is not working because my block isn't deleted. Nothing happens when I call it nothing happens and I don't get error message. I made mistake it's if tool == 5

Comment: If I click on existing block with tool == 5, found is printed

Comment: For `tool == 5`, `test` is a tuple (`test=(xg*GRID, yg*GRID)`). So what do you expect `c.delete(test)` does because `test` is not a valid item ID or tag?  Also I wonder what the result of `t = c.find_withtag('point')`? Is there any item with tag `point`?

Comment: I found solution by making some change in variables. I was using wrong item ID and after that was able to remove blocks exept first placed, I found problem which was in another part of the code. Thanks for your help :)